# "There is no “reference-to-member” type in C + +", std::bind and boost::bind are in the same boat

Tags: c++, reference, standards, pointer-to-member, member-functions

Quoting the standard (2003) version (the more recent others are saying the same I think) very end of 8.3.3, bold emphasizing is mine :

> A pointer to member shall not point to a static member of a class (9.4), a member with reference type, or
>   “cv void.” [Note: see also 5.3 and 5.5. The type “pointer to member” is distinct from the type “pointer”,
>   that is, a pointer to member is declared only by the pointer to member declarator syntax, and never by the
>   pointer declarator syntax. **There is no “reference-to-member” type in C + +**. ]

But I see for instance a lot of

```
boost::bind(&SomeClass::SomeMemberFunction, this, _1)
```

as well as

```
std::bind(&SomeClass::SomeMemberFunction, this, std::placeholders::_1)
```

etc working like a charm, involving `&SomeClass::SomeMemberFunction`'s which seem to be references to member function.

Is the standard simply saying that for instance

```
int (SomeClass::&RefOnSomeMemberFunction) (int) = SomeClass::SomeMemberFunction
```

is not a valid assertion in that language, or is there more ?

Comment: `&` is addressof operator.

Comment: So what the standard says is simply that, for instance, `int (SomeClass::&RefOnSomeMemberFunction) (int) = SomeClass::SomeMemberFunction` is not a valid assertion in the language ?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of the wording is correct. The following is ill-formed:

```
int (SomeClass::&RefOnSomeMemberFunction) (int) = SomeClass::SomeMemberFunction;
```

In fact, if you look at the grammar rules, there's only

> nested-name-specifier * attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> cv-qualifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> `D1`

---

Your understanding of what happens in the calls to `boost::bind` and `std::bind` you mentioned is flawed. In this context, [unary `&`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) is the addressof operator, and it yields *pointer* to member (function). That pointer is defined in the paragraph you quoted.

Comment: Thx again for the clarification !

Answer (score 0):

C++ class's member function implicitly uses `this` as the first parameter.
So `std::bind(&SomeClass::SomeMemberFunction, this, std::placeholders::_1)` can be explained as:

1. Get the function pointer address of `SomeClass::SomeMemberFunction`;
2. Use `this` as the first parameter of the function, here `this` is the object's address;
3. Use `std::placeholders::_1` as the second parameter.

Then you get a `functor`, that will call the `object`'s `SomeMemberFunction` with placeholder `_1`.

Comment: How is that an answer to whether the standard allows references to members?

Comment: I thought @user10000100_u didnot understand how `std::bind` works, and I try to explain how it works.